# How to use FeathersJS REST in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables, feathersjs

I'm struggling to get Feathers in Angular to work against a Feathers REST server. It seems that it makes no request.

I have a Feathers server with the resource http://example.com/app/experiences that is returning data in Feathers paginated format:

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "limit": 10,
    "skip": 0,
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "5db5ef8dc64f59001d750c72",
            ... etc ..,
        }
    ]
```

On client, I have a Feathers service that centralizes all services configuration:

```
@Injectable()
export class Feathers {
  private _feathers = feathers();                     
  private feathersRestClient = feathersRestClient('http://example.com/app');

  constructor() {
    this._feathers
      .configure(this.feathersRestClient.angular)
      .configure(rx({                          
        idField: '_id'
      }));

    this._feathers.use('/experiences', new FeathersGenericService());
  }

  // expose services
  public service(name: string) {
    return this._feathers.service(name);
  }
}
```

The FeathersGenericService is just a generic class I got from https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/services.html#service-methods:

```
export class FeathersGenericService implements ServiceMethods<any>  {
  async find(params: Params) {}
  async get(id: Id, params: Params) {}
  async create(data: any, params: Params) {}
  async update(id: NullableId, data: any, params: Params) {}
  async patch(id: NullableId, data: any, params: Params) {}
  async remove(id: NullableId, params: Params) {}
}
```

Then I have a simple ExperienceService that just finds first 25 results:

```
export class ExperienceService {

  constructor(private feathers: Feathers) { }


  experiences$() {
    return from((this.feathers
      .service('experiences'))
      .watch()
      .find({
        query: {
          $limit: 25
        }
      }));
  }        

}
```

And finally, the component:

```
export class ExperienceListComponent implements OnInit {
  experiences$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private eservice: ExperienceService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eservice.experiences$().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      return res;
    });
  }
}
```

How ever "res" is undefined... In the network tab I see no request to the API has been made.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: I've created this Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfysld

There's a bug with Stackblitz and Feathers, so it does not compile, but compiles in local once downloaded.

Comment: you need to `subscribe` your `experiences$` observable in order to make an HTTP call.

Comment: Thanks Syed, however it's still not working... In ExperienceListComponent:
   ngOnInit() {
    this.eservice.experiences$().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      return res;
    });
  }
 I got undefined in res. Still no http call to API is made..

Answer (score 2):

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
...
return from(this.feathers
      .service('/experiences')
      .find({
        query: {
          $limit: 25
        }
      }));
```

Feathers find method returns a Promise. You need to convert it to an Observable.

Comment: Thanks HarlockBcn, but stlil the same behavior.. I've created this Stackblitz if you want to see complete code:   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfysld

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57792756/how-to-display-feathersjs-client-results-in-angular

Comment: That post shows the use of "from", I did that already earlier. Checkout the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfysld?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fexperience.service.ts. Plus this example uses sockets..